# Images inaccessible from asset catalog in a SwiftUI framework

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, asset-catalog

I've created an iOS framework that contains a single SwiftUI `View`. I've then added an Asset Catalog with a single image. Trying to access that image from the SwiftUI view doesn't do anything - I see a blank image.

`Image("MyImage")`

The Xcode Preview doesn't show anything, nor does the view show anything for a test target I wrote that uses the framework.

So the question is - how do I bundle images with a framework that uses SwiftUI? Is this not supported? The only way I could get this to work was to move the image to the test target's asset catalog instead. Unfortunately this means that I cannot preview the designs I'm working on when developing the framework.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

By default

`Image("MyImage")` is `Image("MyImage", bundle: Bundle.main)`

ie. in bundle of application.

You have to explicitly specify bundle (of framework) in which Assets catalog is located, as

`Image("MyImage", bundle: bundle)`

where `bundle` is instantiated in usual way by class or identifier.

Comment: Oh my God.. THANK you! This was driving me insane!

Comment: You are real MVP mate. This is how to specify you bundle:  
Image("image_name", bundle: Bundle(identifier:"com.framework.identifier"))

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Searched too long for this answer :(

Comment: it works :) Just keep the Asset catalog in the root hierarchy.

Comment: Image("xxx", bundle: .module) works for me

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can load a custom image or custom SF Symbol within a Swift Package.

The SwiftUI invocation is:

```
Image(“my-symbol-name“, bundle: .module)
```